# Gnuplot and PDFLatex question

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to use Gnuplot and package `gnuplottex` to create plots directly in LaTeX. Started with the following simple example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[shell]{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf,terminaloptions={font ",10" linewidth 3}]
plot sin(x), cos(x)
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

When I run

```bsh
pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-shell %.tex
```

I get the following warning messages:

```
Package gnuplottex Warning:Shell escape not enabled

Package gnuplottex Warning:Please convert example1-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot manually

...
```

No pages of output.

I'm using MikTeX, TeXmaker and Gnuplot 4.5.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried running it with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 %.tex`?

Comment: AFAIK, the option is either `--enable-write18` or `--shell-escape`, not `--enable-shell`.

Comment: Since you just seem to be starting out with producing plots in LaTeX: May I recommend you take a look at the `pgfplots` package? It's a very user friendly and powerful plotting package that creates plots that integrate perfectly with your document, and it can use Gnuplot as a backend (you can use raw Gnuplot code if you wish).

Comment: Since you're using Miktex, you'll have to use `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}`.

Comment: interesting automation article [Fun with gnuplot and arara](http://www.latex-community.org/arara.pdf)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When using MikTeX, you need to load `gnuplottex` with the `[miktex]` option.

Note that you might be better off using the `pgfplots` package, which generates plots completely within LaTeX (or uses gnuplot as its backend). This integrates the plots much better into the document, since the same font and rendering is used for the text and the plot. It also makes it easier to annotate the plot.

Here's an example comparing the result of using `gnuplottex` to that of `pgfplots` (using gnuplot for the calculations):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\section{GnuplotTeX}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf, terminaloptions={font "Arial"}]
plot sin(x), cos(x)
\end{gnuplot}

\section{PGFPLOTS}
Note how the tick labels match the document font.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-10:10, samples=50, smooth, no markers, enlargelimits=false]
\addplot gnuplot {sin(x)}; \addlegendentry{$\sin(x)$}
\addplot gnuplot {cos(x)}; \addlegendentry{$\cos(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pslatex]` and run latex+dvips. Then you have same font in text and plot with gnuplottex too.

Comment: In pdflatex  you can use `\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]`

Comment: At the moment one can also use either cairolatex that generates directly pdf output with the integration advantages mentioned for epslatex, or, especially if lualatex is used, the tikz terminal, such that there are no big drawbacks in terms of integration. See the gnuplottex documentation for some examples.