# How to use Gnuplots .eps and .tex files at all with pdflatex

Tags: eps, gnuplot, epstopdf, texinputs

I tried to make a plot with data from a .txt file. The part with gnuplot works, but bringing the diagramm to Latex is frustrating. That's what I do:

-- GNUPLOT --

```
set terminal epslatex size 10cm,5.8cm
set output 'Messw1.tex'
plot '~Long Filepath~/mydata.txt' notitle with lines
```

Now there are to files in "My Documents" (On partition C, in case it matters. TexLive 2012 and Gnuplot are on a different Partition.): "Messw1.tex" and "Messw1.eps".

-- LATEX --

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \input{~Long Filepath~/Messw1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

That's the first time in latex I have not the slightest idea, how I can make it work. :)
Desperately needing help!

Comment: For me it seems that question [gnuplot and pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41666/gnuplot-and-pdflatex-question) can help you ...

Comment: What is the problem using the above code? Please update your answer to include the log of (pdf)latex.

Comment: @ Kurt: I know all these threads about gnuplot. In this case, I can't even compile the example in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Josephus if it's not confidential, can you post `mydata.txt` file via dropbox here or any `dummytext.txt` which creates the problem. also post the `Messw1.log`, it's difficult to diagnose unless one knows the full symptoms.

Comment: For a quick start: Use the pdf output of gnuplot instead of eps. Then copy the resulting file into the directory where the latex file is located, include the graphics with `\includegraphics{filename.pdf}` instead of `\input...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some points, that come to my mind:

- I would wonder, whether the classic (dvi)latex, dvips, ps2pdf route works for you? This is mostly to make sure, that it is actually a pdflatex problem and not something else.
- It sometimes can be a problem if .tex/.eps files are not in a subdir of the main document or the like. Could you copy messw1.tex, messw1.eps into the same directory as your main document and `\input messw1.tex`?

#### Alternative options

Not really answering your question now, but if you want some high quality graphs in your document, that use tex for labels, you might want to take a look at [GLE](http://glx.sf.net/).

Comment: Oh my gosh! I didn't know, the .tex and .eps files of the plot have to be in the same directory of the compiling .tex file. I always had them somewhere entirely else.
I know it's a fundamental thing you'd assume others would know; to such an extend that nobody writes about it. Many thanks! :D
It does work now, if they are in the very same directory, like
        `\input{Messw1}`
but doesn't work when I put the .eps/.tex files in a subdirectory "Diagrams" with
        `\input{Diagrams/Messw1}`
,saying `LaTeX Error: File 'Messw1' not found.`

Comment: @Josephus [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: I wonder, whether `\input Diagrams/Messw1.tex` (with `.tex` and no `{}`) works?

Comment: @ Elrond: No, still can't use subdirectories. This leaves me rather unsatisfied, but at least it works at all.

Comment: Is it the .tex file that is not found? Or the autogenerated pdf? I know that I had weird issues with epstopdf and subdirectories. The solution for me was to add `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}` to the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

Just make gnuplot output PDF, or transform the EPS to PDF somehow. pdflatex doesn't handle eps or ps figures.