# Font management, i.e. problems with StandardSymL-Slant_167

Tags: fonts, pdftex, adobe

my Illustrator doesn't know about the font "StandardSymL-Slant_167", which seems to be used in a picture that I createted with gnuplot+pdflatex.
At the moment Illustrator is replacing it with another (quite useless) font. I know where to store fonds for the Illustrator. But I just can't find the .ttf file used by latex to creat the picture.

I tryed a workaround already, in the sence that I added

```
\pdfmapline{psyr Symbol}
\font\sy=psyr
```

to my header in the creation process. This partly worked, in the sence that Illustrator could handle the font now, but the font wasn't properly rasterized or vectorized (or whatever is done by the two lines ... finally it was just hugh pixels).

So could someone please help me? I would of course also use another font which looks similar, just dont know how!

Edit:
While I created the minimal working example, I already realized that the problem is related to the mathptmx package (the same is true for the T1 package). If I don't use this, the issue is gone, but than my lables are ugly. Here is the minimal example:

```
#Gnuplot script file for plotting data 
set terminal epslatex standalone color header \
"\\usepackage{mathptmx}"

plot sin(x) title '$\sin(\mu)$'
```

Now I create a .tex file with gnuplot and compile it with pfdlatex. Actually I realized that pdflatex has no T1 font called Helvetica so he uses another "standard" font:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/Helvetica/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 59.
```

Opening this in the Illustrator will make him complain about missing fonts.

Edit: I found a way around the issue. If I compile first with latex and than use dvipdf I don't get the issue. I guess now only ps-fonts (or whatever) are used, which are familiar to Adobe. Still this is not a real solution, but for me it's so far working.

Comment: Please post a Minimum Working Example i.e. code people can compile to reproduce the problem you are having. This will make it easier for people to help effectively.

Comment: I did so. I hope it helps.

Comment: Which 'T1' package? Is that specific to `gnuplot`? I can't find any `t1.sty` in my installation of TeX Live.

Comment: Does e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102008/how-to-use-gnuplots-eps-and-tex-files-at-all-with-pdflatex?lq=1 help at all?

Comment: T1 is a latex package (\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}). I think it's mainly used in germany. It allows to use things like ä, ö, ü and has proper hyphenation.

Comment: @cfr: The link is a bit too general.

Comment: Oh. You mean `fontenc`. `T1` is the option you're passing. `fontenc` is the package. It is widely used. I use it in every document I write.