# raw gnuplot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot, shell-escape

I have a problem with the gnuplot environment in pgfplots. I already set "--enable-write18" in the argument of pdfLaTeX and added the path of gnuplot.exe to the PATH-variable in the advanced system options.

My problem now is that I can pass code in gnuplot (see picture), below are the 3 lines which I can't pass in the raw-gnuplot-environment in the tikzpicture (see code). What do I wrong? Can someone help, please?

pdfLaTeX-code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[paperwidth=27cm,paperheight=17cm,margin=0in,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\begin{document}



\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [width=21cm, height=14cm,
    tick label style={font=\large},
    xmin=7700, xmax=7810,
    ymin=0, ymax=0.05,
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line=box
    ]
    \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, id=test, mark=none]{
    set xrange [7700:7810];
    set yrange [0:0.05];
    plot "test.txt" using ($1):($2) with lines;
    };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

gnuplot-picture:
[image: gnuplot, works]

and finally my data-file:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-7764417/test.txt.html

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't tell us what error you're experiencing, so I can only guess at a possible solution: The problem is that, even though you restrict the plot range in gnuplot to x=7700:7810, gnuplot actually writes all the data entries into its output table. It merely marks the points outside the range using an `o` in the last column. PGFPlots then chokes on the huge amount of data it has to process (150000 points).

What you can do to work around your problem is to use the `using` syntax in `gnuplot` to process only a subset of the data. If you say

```
plot "test.txt" using ($1):($2) every 1:1:100500::105000 with lines;
```

`gnuplot` will process all the points starting with the the first block (there's only one block in your data), starting with line 100500, continuing until the last block, ending at line 105000. This range happens to include the values within your desired x range:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [width=21cm, height=14cm,
    tick label style={font=\large},
    xmin=7700, xmax=7810,
    xtick={7700,7725,...,7800},
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line=box
    ]
    \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, id=test, mark=none]{
    set xrange [7700:7810];
    set yrange [0:0.05];
    plot "test.txt" using ($1):($2) every 1:1:100500::105000 with lines;
    };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!!
I just don't get where the numbers 100500 and 105000 come from? ..because if I try it with another file which has an header and is nearly twice bigger it doesn't work anymore

Comment: btw: there is no error shown in the compiler, just an empty tikzpicture in the pdf

Comment: @Andy Guess: I think 100500 might be the starting `index` corresponding to xdata=7700 and 105000 would be index corresponding to xdata=7810

Comment: @Andy Which software generates the `test.txt` and its header ? Jake's answer is an demo _example_, it's not suited for a complicated case of data with header files. Hence post it as new follow up Q or update current Q with the structure of header if it can be read by gnuplot ?

Comment: @texenthusiast: A couple of minor corrections: There's no downsampling involved in this approach, all data points in the range of interest are plotted. And the start and end index don't have to correspond exactly to the start and end x value (the `xrange` is still applied). And this approach works independently of whether the datafile has a header or not. Apart from that, you're right of course that this is just a workaround, since you need to somehow find the appropriate start and end indices.

Comment: thanks, I fond the right range!
but there's still a problem -.-
I am going to post a new question, if you don't mind?

Comment: @Jake Thanks. Yes corrected in my answer as `Selecting interested range of points` instead of down sampling.

Answer (score 4):

Selecting interested *range of points* in gnuplot for oversized data files is the *good* approach while plotting in pgfplots as suggested by Jake. The `filename.test.table` data size is smaller since selective points are only written by gnuplot engine, thereby easing the load on pgfplots.

Using [gnuplottex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex) as an alternative solution to plot entire `test.txt` data and zooming in the interested x,y range as in Q.

[image]

**Works with: -shell-escape(TeXLive) or --enable-write18(MiKTeX) enabled and gnuplot 4.4.1**

**code compiled with: multiple runs of pdflatex,TeXLive distro 2013 on Linux**

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} for MiKTeX
%\usepackage{gnuplottex} for TeXLive on Linux
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex
\begin{document}   
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf]
plot [7700:7810] [0:0.05] 'test.txt' using 1:2 with lines;
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

Another approach(not *encouraged*) is to use `LuaLaTeX` engine (close relative of pdfLaTeX) with `--enable-write18`. LuaLaTeX  can handle more points( memory capacity) but it's very slow for obvious reasons of data size.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[tick label style={font=\large},
    xmin=7700, xmax=7810,
    ymin=0, ymax=0.05,
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line=box
    ]
    \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, id=test, mark=none]{
    set xrange [7700:7810];
    set yrange [0:0.05];
    plot "test.txt" using ($1):($2) with lines;
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: somehow your code doesn't compile, I get an empty pdf.

Comment: I have compiled on Linux with `-shell-escape` and gnuplot 4.4.1. For MiKTeX (I don't have it as I am on Linux) see if `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}` works with `--enable-write18` enabled. Remember to run pdflatex twice or thrice until you notice the figure.

Comment: @Andy  let me know if `[miktex]` works I should add these words inside Q and clear the comments.

Comment: ... still doesn't work, I guess I have to check out the gnuplottex package... or get Linux^^

Comment: ok, I added it in the MiKTeX Package Manager ... but still no picture

Comment: @Andy `still no picture`/`doesn't compile`/`doesn't work` are for people close to your monitor as we are in _Virtual world_,kindly report the errors and take us with you to help you better. Some MiKTeX User might give hints over time. Try with [pfgplots and gnuplottex examples by Jake](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41669/15717)

Comment: @Andy Use LuaLaTeX engine for large data points incase of emergency purposes.

Comment: @texenthusiast - I think you have a typo; you've written `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} for MiKTeX` - while I guess you wanted to comment that last part: `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} % for MiKTeX` ...

Comment: @sdaau yes you are right, you may edit it. I don't want to bump the thread for a minor edit. may be later...