# Gnuplot inside LaTeX not working

Tags: gnuplot, vim

I'm trying to create a gnuplot image inside my LaTeX document, but nothing is being displayed.

My gnuplot works if I do it outside LaTeX.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf, terminaloptions=color, scale=0.9]
set title 'Laptop Steps'
set datafile separator ','
set xlabel 'Query'
set ylabel 'Average time in ms(100 executions)'
set xrange [0:21]
set xtics 1,1,20
set logscale y
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb '#bbbbbb'
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb '#bbbbbb'
set key samplen 2 spacing .5 font ',8'
show grid
set style fill solid 0.8 border -1
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
plot for [i=1:14] 'benchmarks/basex-steps-laptop-transposed.csv' u (\$0+1):i title ''.i.'00    kb' with linespoints
\end{gnuplot}              
\end{figure}
```

I'm using vim with the latex plugin.
The structure of my project is:

```
main
  |-chapters/the-file-with-the-gnuplot-code
  |-benchmarks/benchmark-file.csv
```

For gnuplot I have this in my document:

```
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

I only get the warning:

> Package gnuplottex Warning: Please convert thesis-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot manually

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You must use `-shell-escape` when calling `pdflatex`, see the third sentence in the gnuplottex-documentation. And you don't need the `epstopdf` package if you're using the pdf terminal.

Comment: Hi! It seems to me that your question is very similar to this one: [Gnuplot and PDFLatex question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41666/gnuplot-and-pdflatex-question?rq=1). Please have a look, and if the one I link above helps you, we can mark the questions as duplicates of each other.

Comment: @Christoph I'm using -shell-escape, I should have written this into my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run `gnuplot <basename>-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot`, you'll see `gnuplot`'s error message

```
plot for [i=1:14] 'benchmarks/test.csv' u (\$0+1):i title ''.i.'00    kb' with linespoints
                                           ^
"texse-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot", line 16: invalid character \
```

`gnuplot` is stumbling over the `\$`. You don't need to escape the dollar sign in a `gnuplot` environment. If you remove the backslash, everything should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf, terminaloptions=color, scale=0.9]
set title 'Laptop Steps'
set datafile separator ','
set xlabel 'Query'
set ylabel 'Average time in ms(100 executions)'
set xrange [0:21]
set xtics 1,1,20
set logscale y
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb '#bbbbbb'
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb '#bbbbbb'
set key samplen 2 spacing .5 font ',8'
show grid
set style fill solid 0.8 border -1
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
plot for [i=1:14] 'benchmarks/test.csv' u ($0+1):i title ''.i.'00    kb' with linespoints
set out
\end{gnuplot}              
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good catch! I think that the question title should be edited to include `$`, so that this is a good reference for other people. As well, my comment above about being a duplicate is obviously wrong.

Comment: That's why I always recommend to use `column(0)` instead of `$0` when calling gnuplot from another program/script. That avoids any escaping issues.